# Razer Blade Stealth touchpad jumps with Linux

Tags: manjaro, laptop, cursor, libinput

### **My Issue**

I am using the 2016 model Razer Blade Stealth laptop. Recently, I've decided to install Linux on it. Whenever I use the touchpad on any Linux OS I've loaded onto it so far, the cursor jumps around at what seems to be entirely random, usually just a small distance in any direction. I've looked for solutions for over a week now and have tried everything I could find that's already online; no luck. I know it isn't an issue with the hardware because **the touchpad works perfectly fine on Windows 10**.

The cursor does not jitter or jump whenever I'm just resting my finger on the touchpad, it only occurs when I am moving it. There  also seems to be no consistent spots where it tends to jump around.

### **What I've tried**

Since this appears to be an issue with ALL Linux distrobutions I've tried so far, I've decided to stick with **manjaro community edition with i3**, which runs on Arch Linux.

```
[name@name-pc ~]$ uname -r
4.14.66-1-MANJARO
```

I've tried -

- Installing xf86-input-synaptics
- Editing `/usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-evdev.hwdb`and shifting the fuzz zone up and down; no difference.
- following the instructions in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983419/touchpad-makes-mouse-go-in-a-grid-like-pattern-external-mouse-doesnt/987271#987271) post

Those three things are the only things I found to try. It may be possible that I'm not following the instructions correctly?

Comment: Please state why you down-voted. It doesn't help anyone to let nobody know why you don't like the post. In my opinion, it's well structured and portrays a clear issue that many people are having with Linux kernel version before 17 on not only the Razer Blade Stealth, but other laptops as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've had exactly the same issue, the following steps helped me solve it :

- On manjaro/arch linux : Install `libinput-git` from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libinput-git/)  to pick up the following change in `libinput` that should solve the issue: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput/merge_requests/99 that. You should note that compiling libinput may require other packages
  (`python-sphinx`, etc...)
- Reboot your pc

If it works, profit !

Else, you may want to tweak the fuzz value :

- `sudo libinput measure fuzz --fuzz=4`
- `sudo udevadm hwdb --update`
- `reboot`

If the fuzz value **4** does not work, try with **8** or **12** or **16**

More details about touchpad fuzz and jitter here : https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/touchpad-jitter.html

Comment: I'll give it a try when I get home and let you know how it goes. Thanks!
As a note: I installed the latest Ubuntu release and then updated the kernel to it's latest available release and this fixed it! Though if I can, I think I'd like to run manjaro. Thanks again!